# How to create a F# Azure Functions (v1 & v2) Project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: azure, f#, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I want to easily create a F# Azure Functions (v2) Project in Visual Studio 2017.

Is there some ZIP file with a Template F# project that I can use and publish using Visual Studio Publish context menu?

I would like that VS has a F# Azure Function Project template, like it has for C#.

[image: C# Azure Function Project Template]

[image: Publish Menu]

Answer (score 8):

Azure Functions templates for F# are missing, which means lack of possibility to create F# precompiled projects in Visual Studio and Functions CLI.

There is an open [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-templates/issues/627) to introduce such support. Even though it's not apparent from this issue, I was told that templates are coming very soon.

For now, you need to:

- Create a generic F# class library project
- Reference Functions SDK NuGet package
- Add a static method for your Function

You could use [this sample](https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/azure-functions-fsharp-examples/tree/master/5-precompiled) as a starting point, but be sure to update to latest versions of NuGet packages.

Comment: A generic F# class library project would be missing the Publish feature.

Comment: @Tony arghs... Do you know which bit of `csproj` make Publish appear for C# functions?

Comment: I don´t know. But with this missing piece, we will have (almost?) ready Azure Functions F# Project Template.

Comment: Or you can just use [wizard from Rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2019/05/09/building-azure-functions-sql-database-improvements-azure-toolkit-rider-2019-1/)

Answer (score 7):

For me, I had to go through converting a C# function project into F#:

1. Create C# Azure Function Project
2. rename `.csproj` to `.fsproj`
3. Edit the `.fsproj` file and make sure the following items are in there:

---

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Function1.fs" />
    <Content Include="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

---

Make sure you set `host.json` and `local.settings.json` to `<Content...` instead of `<None...` so it copies it to the output file.

4. Make sure you have the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` installed
5. Your `Function1.fs` file should look something like that (for an `HttpTrigger`)

---

```
namespace FunctionApp1

open System
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host
open System;
open System.IO;
open System.Threading.Tasks;
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

module Function1 =
    [<FunctionName("Function1")>]
    let Run ([<HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, [|"post"|])>] req: HttpRequest) (log: ILogger) = 
        async {
            return "some result"
        }
        |> Async.StartAsTask
```

---

6. Now you are ready to deploy. Just right click on the project and click `Publish...`
7. Select `Azure Function App` and follow the instructions. Make sure to select `Run from pakcage file`.

[image]